# How to use UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: nil) in SwiftUI to move focus to specific view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I have a button on screen. When a user taps that button, my app opens a modal (view). When the user then closes that view, the focus of accessibility VoiceOver goes to the top of the screen. In UIKit, I can use [UIAccessibility.post(notification:argument:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615194-post) passing [.layoutChanged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/notification/1620186-layoutchanged) into the `notification` parameter and passing a reference to one of my views into the `argument` parameter. How can I achieve this same behaviour in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

How I managed this was using a `.accessibilityHidden` wrapper on the very top level of the parent view and then used a @State variable as the value to pass into `accessibilityHidden`. This way the parent view is ignored while the modal is showing. And then reintroduced into the view once the modal is closed again.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var showingModal = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                showingModal = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Open Modal")
            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingModal, onDismiss: {
               print("Focus coming back to main view")
            } content: {
                Modal()
            })
        }
        .accessibilityHidden(self.showingModal)
    }
}

struct Modal: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Focus will move here")
            Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Close Modal to Refocus Back")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also chain multiple modal / alerts as long at you have @State values to handle the changes to them so the focus moves properly

```
.accessibilityHidden(self.showingModel1 || self.showingModel2 || self.showingAlert1 || self.showingAlert2)
```

I know this question is really old, but I literally just was handling this and thought if someone else stumbled onto this question there would be an answer here.